# Raspberry Pi 4 gets stuck booting Ubuntu 18.04.5, "rcu_sched detected stalls"

Tags: boot, raspberrypi

I flashed the Ubuntu 18.04.5 image for Raspberry Pi 4 (`ubuntu-18.04.5-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi4.img`) to an SD card and powered my RPi4 off of the 5V GPIO pin.

When booting, it gets up to this point:

```
[    4.352613] random: fast init done
[    4.414200] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
[    4.423077] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC32G 29.7 GiB
[    4.431244] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    4.437267]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
```

Then there is a 24 second pause before it prints:

```
[   28.006460] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
[   28.012484] rcu:     1-...0: (7 ticks this GP) idle=1d6/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=80/81 fqs=7 
[   28.021231]  (detected by 3, t=5893 jiffies, g=-379, q=2)
[   28.026710] Task dump for CPU 1:
[   28.029984] swapper/0       R  running task        0     1      0 0x0000002a
[   28.037143] Call trace:
[   28.039636]  __switch_to+0xcc/0x208
[   28.043179]  console_unlock+0x4f8/0x600
[   28.047076] rcu: rcu_sched kthread starved for 1001 jiffies! g-379 f0x0 RCU_GP_WAIT_FQS(5) ->state=0x402 ->cpu=3
[   28.057405] rcu: RCU grace-period kthread stack dump:
[   28.062529] rcu_sched       I    0    10      2 0x00000028
[   28.068098] Call trace:
[   28.070580]  __switch_to+0xcc/0x208
[   28.074123]  __schedule+0x2c4/0x7b0
[   28.077663]  schedule+0x38/0xa8
[   28.080851]  schedule_timeout+0x1a0/0x378
[   28.084920]  rcu_gp_kthread+0x688/0xa10
[   28.088813]  kthread+0x124/0x128
[   28.092089]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x1c
```

Another minute or so later, it prints a similar trace:

```
[   92.006458] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
[   92.012475] rcu:     1-...0: (7 ticks this GP) idle=1d6/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=80/81 fqs=23 
[   92.021308]  (detected by 3, t=21893 jiffies, g=-379, q=2)
[   92.026874] Task dump for CPU 1:
[   92.030147] swapper/0       R  running task        0     1      0 0x0000002a
[   92.037304] Call trace:
[   92.039788]  __switch_to+0xcc/0x208
[   92.043328]  console_unlock+0x4f8/0x600
[   92.047223] rcu: rcu_sched kthread starved for 1001 jiffies! g-379 f0x0 RCU_GP_WAIT_FQS(5) ->state=0x402 ->cpu=3
[   92.057552] rcu: RCU grace-period kthread stack dump:
[   92.062675] rcu_sched       I    0    10      2 0x00000028
[   92.068242] Call trace:
[   92.070726]  __switch_to+0xcc/0x208
[   92.074265]  __schedule+0x2c4/0x7b0
[   92.077804]  schedule+0x38/0xa8
[   92.080991]  schedule_timeout+0x1a0/0x378
[   92.085060]  rcu_gp_kthread+0x688/0xa10
[   92.088952]  kthread+0x124/0x128
[   92.092227]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x1c
```

and so forth, about every minute.

I do not get a console login prompt and there aren't messages that are otherwise related to booting that I would expect.

How can I diagnose this problem further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the 18.04.5 release for Raspberry Pi 4 (64-bit) is currently broken. I filed [an issue with the Ubuntu project](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1895550) for further discussion. Installing the 18.04.4 image works.